# C++ changing length of a structure made from an int variable and a pointer to long question

Tags: c++, struct, long-integer

I have created a struct in C++ of the following type:

```
struct longsir {
    int len;
    long *sir;
    int isinitialised;};
```

Now, I have to modify the length of a structure, for which I used the following function:

```
longsir modlen(longsir *s, int newlen){
    if (s ->isinitialised ==1 && newlen != s->len) {
        if (newlen < s-> len) {
            longsir a;
            a.len=newlen;
            a.isinitialised=1;
            a.sir=new long[a.len];
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<newlen;i++){
                a.sir[i]=s->sir[i];};
            return a;}
        else {
            longsir a;
            int i; int oldlen=s->len;
            a.len=newlen;
            a.isinitialised=1;
            a.sir=new long[a.len];
            for (i=0;i<(s->len);i++){
                a.sir[i]=s->sir[i];};
            cout <<"Introduceti restul elementelor din sir ";
            //Code works till here
            for(i=oldlen;i>newlen;i++){
                cout <<"Introduceti elementele sirului cu numarul "<<i<<endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin >> a.sir[i];}
                return a;}}}
```

So, when I choose to use a value bigger than the initial length of the initial array, the code at first creates a new array, after that copies the data from the old array and asks the user to fill in the remaining cells from stdin. Anyway, when running the program, it only asks for introduction of the remaining elements, and after that automatically initialises them to 0. Why is it that the code doesn't work as suggested? I can't find any clue about this situation. Thank you very much for your help.

P.S. You can see the entire original code on Pastebin: [the main function](http://pastebin.com/ND5KWfdf) and [the header file](http://pastebin.com/VC3nLFKv)

Comment: I don't like what you're doing with your `}`s.

Comment: Replace fields `len` and `sir` with `std::vector<long> vec`. It will save you a lot of coding and a huge memory leak.

Comment: Tadeusz Kopec, thanks for your suggestion. It's just a lab work, so I don't think that it would be so vital to use new, more complex, types of objects, while in the real-life problems I'll surely use it.

Comment: If you regard the vector class a a black box, I'd say the std::vector-based solution is even less complex.

Comment: Even if you don't care about memory leaks, a vector is much simpler than a manually-managed dynamic array. For one thing, you won't have to write (or debug) functions like this.

Comment: Axel, Mike Seymour, it's not that I don't care about memory leaks. The teacher demands that we manually manage the memory. I hate it too, but have no other choice. Anyway, thank you very much for your advices

Answer (score 1):

`for(i=oldlen;i>newlen;i++){` maybe i < newlen

Answer (score 0):

`for(i=oldlen;i>newlen;i++)` there have to be `i < newlen` I think.

Comment: `why i <= newlen.` Index starts from zero and the allocated number of longs are newlen. I believe i< newlen is fine. What do you say?